# How can I break a Vigenère cipher with partial plain key?

Tags: classical-cipher, vigenere

I've got the cypher text: `cöimamiçknsyznhaczstş` and a partial plain key: `?ğre??i`

I've used "?" instead of unknown characters.

The question is: is it possible to find the whole key?

I've read about given partial text and unknown key some people found the key and text.

My problem is easier than others. I'm sure It can be found but how?

2 vowels cannot come together in turkish. I've tried about vowel and consonant words but I couldn't find any clue

Turkish alphabet = 'abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyz'

Comment: I can see at first sight your key. Nonetheless, since a three characters from the key is given sequentially You just need to concentrate on this part And look at the words around them to reveal the plaintext and the key.

Comment: what is your key length? 7 character? : **ğre??i** as shown above?